# How to pass argument value from one module to another?

Tags: javascript, module, arguments, game-development

I'm trying to implement a functionality to a game of Tic Tac Toe.

1. const **"startModule"** - Player should be able to select X or O on the start screen.
2. Then the value should be assigned to an argument **"playerChoice"**, which I'm trying to pass to "gameModule".
3. In **"gameModule"**, the "playerChoice" argument is being assigned to "circleTurn".
4. Based on the "circleTurn value, script should assign css value ("X_CLASS" or "CIRCLE_CLASS") to the "currentClass" argument in the "handleClick" function. This is where things are not working.

I'm still learning and would appreciate any help or pointers :)

edit: I've cut a lot from previous js section and left only substantial info (I hope)

```
const startModule = (() => {
  
  let xButton = document.getElementById("player-choiceX")
  let oButton = document.getElementById("player-choiceO")
  let playerChoice;
  
  const xoChoice = () => {
    
    xButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      playerChoice = false;
      document.getElementById("playerChoice").style.display = "none";
      console.log(playerChoice);
    })
  }
  
  return {
    xoChoice, playerChoice
  };
  
})();


const gameModule = (() => {

    const board = document.getElementById("board");
    const X_CLASS = 'x';
    const CIRCLE_CLASS = 'circle';
    const resetButton = document.getElementById("reset");
    const winningMessageElement = document.getElementById("winningMessage");
    const cellElements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-cell]");
    const winningMessageTextElement = document.querySelector("[data-winning-message-text]");
    let circleTurn = playerChoice
  
    const WINNING_COMBINATIONS = [
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 3, 6],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8],
        [0, 4, 8],
        [2, 4, 6],
      ]
      
    const startGame = () => {
      
        resetButton.addEventListener('click', startGame);
        cellElements.forEach(cell => {
          cell.classList.remove(X_CLASS)
          cell.classList.remove(CIRCLE_CLASS)
          cell.removeEventListener('click', handleClick)
          cell.addEventListener('click', handleClick, {once: true})
        })
        setBoardHoverClass()
        winningMessageElement.classList.remove('show')
    }  
      
    const handleClick = (e) => {
        const cell = e.target
        const currentClass = circleTurn ? CIRCLE_CLASS : X_CLASS
        placeMark(cell, currentClass) 
        if (checkWin(currentClass)){
          endGame()
        } else if(isDraw()) {
          endGame(true)
        } else {
          swapTurns();
          setBoardHoverClass();
        }
    }
     
    }
    return {
        startGame, handleClick
    }
  
  })();
  
  startModule.xoChoice()
  gameModule.startGame()
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <script src="index2.js" defer></script>
    <title>TicTacToe</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="player-choice" id="playerChoice">
        <div class="xOrCircle">
                <div class="player-choiceX" id="player-choiceX"></div>
                <div class="player-choiceO" id="player-choiceO"></div>
        </div>
    </div>


    </div>
    <div class="board" id="board">

        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        
    </div>
    <div class="winning-message" id="winningMessage">
        <div data-winning-message-text></div>
        <button id="reset">Reset</button>
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: any chance you could simplify this to focus on your problem area? Good job presenting a lot of information.  It is likely too much though, a focused question can help get answers https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you for your comment @ThisGuy, I've rephrased my post a little bit and I did cut a lot from the js section, hope this will make this clearer. I'm not sure if HTML is needed in this case. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few things about what you have that I want to point out.

For the sake of explaining things, I am going to rewrite your `startModule` to make it easier to digest

```
const startModule = (() => {

  let playerChoice;

  const xoChoice = () => {
      playerChoice = false;
  };

  return {
    xoChoice, playerChoice
  };
})();
```

Based on this version of `startModule`, checkout the outputs from the following code:

```
startModule.playerChoice; // undefined
startModule.xoChoice();
startModule.playerChoice; // undefined
```

Ok so what went wrong that `playerChoice` did not become false? It has to do with something called pass-by-value and pass-by-reference (more on that [here](https://dmitripavlutin.com/value-vs-reference-javascript/thisd))

Basically, because `playerChoice` was assigned a primitive value (`undefined`), when it was returned here:

```
return {
  xoChoice, playerChoice
};
```

The return statement only returned the primitive value `undefined`, not a reference to say an Object.

Fortunately, there is a work around, by utilizing the pass-by-reference functionality in Javascript.

If instead of storing `playerChoice` with a primitive value (`undefined`) and returning it, we could store an Object with the necessary context of the module. This should work because Objects are passed-by-reference, not passed-by-value. The code for this can look something like this:

```
const startModule = (() => {

  let context = {
    playerChoice: undefined    
  }; // This is a JSON Object!

  const xoChoice = () => {
    context.playerChoice = false;
  };

  return {
    xoChoice, context
  };
})();
```

Now let's look at what is outputted from the following code based on this version of startModule:

```
startModule.context.playerChoice; // undefined
startModule.xoChoice();
startModule.context.playerChoice; // false
```

It works! This is the case because since we are returning an Object (`context`), so we are returning a reference to a place of storage (to my knowledge :) ), instead of returning a primitive value (ex. `undefined`, `false`) with no reference to a place in storage. All of this means that the `playerChoice` that is changed when the `xoChoice` function is called is interlinked with the `playerChoice` that is returned when `startModule` is first called.

Ok so how can you utilize this information to share the value of `playerChoice` amongst the modules? For the sake of answering this question, I am going to again, simplify `gameModule` to make things easier to digest.

```
const startModule = (() => {
  // ... (What we previously had)
})();
const gameModule = (() => {
  let circleTurn = context.playerChoice;

  return {
    circleTurn
  };
})();
```

Same as before, let's run some code to see what's happening:

```
startModule.context.playerChoice; // undefined
gameModule.circleTurn; // undefined

startModule.xoChoice();
startModule.context.playerChoice; // false
startModule.circleTurn; // false
```

So there you go, using pass-by-reference we we're able to transmit data from one module (`startModule`), to another (`gameModule`)!

Feel free to ask any other questions, and if you'd like I can show you another interesting alternative way to coding this.

EDIT: Here is the *interesting* (not better or worse) alternative way. With the previous way, you ran a function that did all this stuff to return an informative JSON Object to which you can retrieve information like a normal JSON Object. Instead of making `startModule` the return value of a function, you can simply assign `startModule` to a JSON Object, with functions that do stuff (the stuff from earlier) as value of the Object. It can look something like this:

```
const startModule = {
  playerChoice: undefined,
  xoChoice: function () {
    // 'this' references the 'startModule' Object
    this.playerChoice = false;
  }
}
```

As you notice, `startModule` is now a JSON Object, but still with all the same components as before. It's important to read up about the `this` keyword, as it involves itself heavily with this alternative. (FYI, if you're using arrow functions, `this` keyword is never assigned, so make sure you use ES5 functions if you want to use `this`).

Let's look at the following code and its output:

```
startModule.playerChoice; // undefined;
startModule.xoChoice();
startModule.playerChoice; // false
```

And everything seems to be working fine. While `playerChoice` was initially `undefined`, calling `xoChoice` successfully mutated the value to `false`.

Now there is a small issue with this alternative. Say when you create the `startModule` you want to automatically do some logic (Maybe you want to make an HTTPS request to check the user's Tic Tac Toe win streak, maybe you wanna check if the user is logged in, etc). To do this, it's common practice to assign `init`  to `startModule`, and assign the value to a function that perform initial logic. It can look something like this:

```
const startModule = {
  playerChoice: undefined,
  xoChoice: function () {
    // 'this' references the 'startModule' Object
    this.playerChoice = false;
  },
  init: function () {
    // do initialization stuff
    this.userLoggedIn = true;
  }
}
```

Now obviously, we would need to run `startModule.init()` as soon as we assign `startModule`. Here's a more elegant solution to that:

```
const startModule = {
  playerChoice: undefined,
  xoChoice: function () {
    // 'this' references the 'startModule' Object
    this.playerChoice = false;
  },
  init: function () {
    // do initialization stuff
    this.userLoggedIn = true;

    return this;
  }
}.init();
```

Here, we call `init` as soon as we create the Object, but because `init` returns `this`, we can still assign `startModule` to this function call.

Now let's look at a possible implementation of `gameModule`:

```
const gameModule = {
  board: document.getElementById("board"),
  X_CLASS: 'x',
  CIRCLE_CLASS: 'circle',
  resetButton: document.getElementById("reset"),
  winningMessageElement: document.getElementById("winningMessage"),
  cellElements: document.querySelectorAll("[data-cell]"),
  winnningMessageTextElement: document.querySelector("[data-winning-message-text]"),
  circleTurn: startModule.playerChoice, // look for the playerChoice value in the startModule Object
  WINNING_COMBINATIONS: [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ],
  startGame: function () {
    // 'this' references the Object this function lives under
    this.resetButton.addEventListener('click', this.startGame);
    this.cellElements.forEach(cell => {
      cell.classList.remove(this.X_CLASS)
      cell.classList.remove(this.CIRCLE_CLASS)
      cell.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClick)
      cell.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick, {once: true})
    })
    setBoardHoverClass() // idk where this func comes from
    this.winningMessageElement.classList.remove('show')
  },
  handleClick: function (e) {
    // etc...
  }
}
```

With this implementation, all our variables are stored as key-value pairs, and we use `this` to reference the Object they're in and retrieve their values. You can also see in the value to `circleTurn` that we use `startModule.playerChoice` to get the `playerChoice` value from `startModule`.

I wish I knew the technical name for both these different implementations, but personally I enjoy the alternative I just showed, as it feels simpler to extend upon, and IMO, feels easier to separate logic in a clearer sense. Nonetheless, you do you, both options are perfectly fine and offer their own pros and cons.

Comment: Hi Ares, thank you for your comment. I've modified my code base on your suggestions. Unfortunately, right now I'm getting an error that the "context is not defined". I've updated my post to reflect the changes I've made. If you would be so kind to show another way to do this, I would really appreciate it, but only if you have some spare time :)

Comment: Edit - I can't update my post unfortunately (I'm getting a message I'm spamming). When I'm doing console.log for the start Module "context" object seems to be working. Unfortunately, when I add it to gameModule, I'm getting "undefined" error.

Comment: @Havhar0 sorry there was a little syntax error in the last section I showed.  let circleTurn = context.playerChoice; Should be let circleTurn = startModule.context.playerChoice; You need to grab context from the startModule JSON object. I'll post another answer with an alternative

Comment: Thank you for sharing another method, I'm learning new things thanks to you :) I'm able to pass the argument between modules now. Unfortunately, my function(xoChoice) with event listener from the start module is not updating the playerChoice value. I'm only able to export between the modules what I have declared (JSON Object). I'm searching online how I can resolve this issue, didn't have any luck yet. My intuition tells me that execution order might be wrong. Meaning, when I click on the button, module is exported with default playerChoice value, and after that it's updated